# Fitting a Keras model yields error "constant folding failed: Invalid argument: Unsupported type: 21"

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I am following the example from https://www.tensorflow.org/alpha/tutorials/load_data/text
to load my own dataset and run binary classification on the sentences there (TensorFlow 2.0).
The only change I've made to the example is the dataset being used (which I took from https://github.com/UKPLab/emnlp2017-claim-identification/tree/master/src/main/python), and since the labels can be only 0 or 1 I changed the loss function to `binary_crossentropy` and the optimizer to `RMSprop`.
When fitting the Keras model which is identical to the model proposed in the tutorial, I'm constantly receiving the following error:

```
2019-04-29 13:51:15.609297: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:495] constant folding failed: Invalid argument: Unsupported type: 21
2019-04-29 13:51:15.882000: E tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:495] constant folding failed: Invalid argument: Unsupported type: 21
```

The fitting process is still advancing between those prints as evident from:

```
662/4508 [===>..........................] - ETA: 9:35 - loss: 11.0703 - accuracy: 0.2780
```

but instead of minimizing the loss, it seems to actually be maximizing it, with the accuracy going down after each iteration.
(In fact, if the accuracy metric is correct, it would be a pretty good classifier if I just take `not [prediction]`).
Is there anyone here who can explain to me what is the meaning of this error, and whether it's related to the strange behavior of the model (and hopefully how to fix it)? I've been trying to look for similar errors but couldn't find any.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is one key difference between the Tutorial mentioned in the link, https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/load_data/text and your Dataset.

In the tutorial, Labels are 0, 1 and 2, i.e., all the sentences in `cowper.txt` are Labelled as `0`, all the sentences in `derby.txt` are Labelled as `1`, all the sentences in `butler.txt` are Labelled as `2`. But in your Dataset, Labels are at the end of each sentence of the Text Files.

I have executed the code taking part of your Dataset, as shown below:

```
FILE_NAMES = ['001.dev', '001.test', '001.train', '002.dev', '002.test', '002.train']

parent_dir = "Issue_55902068/OC"

parent_dir
```

In order to handle the difference mentioned above, the function, `labeler` should be modified as shown below:

```
def labeler(example, index):
  Label = tf.strings.split(example, sep="")[-1] #It will give 0 or 1 in Str format
  Label = tf.strings.to_number(Label)
  return example, tf.cast(Label, tf.int64)
```

After that, I changed the loss function to `binary_crossentropy` and the optimizer to `RMSprop` as shown below:

```
model.compile(optimizer='RMSprop', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

It is working as expected. Screenshot of the output is shown below.

[image]